# LocationManager updates every minute, consuming a lot of battery power

Tags: android

I've got some code similar to the following:

```
LocationManager m = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria c = new Criteria();
c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
String provider = m.getBestProvider(c, true);
Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

m.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 900000, 0, pi);
```

Here is the manifest entry for the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver" />
```

Most of the time it works fine, and updates every 15 minutes.  Sometimes, however, it updates every minute, and consumes a bunch of battery power.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:  Is the LocationManager not meant to be used like this for background operations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GPS update interval is faster with good signal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879290/gps-update-interval-is-faster-with-good-signal)

Comment: The solutions there don't really help at all.  If the LocationManager is constantly waking the phone up to update every minute, it's still going to drain the battery even if I check the update time and compare it against the last one.

Comment: what i have noticed is that in android flavors up to and including gingerbread, location manager will give you updates every second or couple of seconds by default.

while running a MIUI flavor of ice cream sandwich, the default is 1 minute, BUT: when i run navigation (foreground OR background) or googlemaps (foreground), i get updates every second or so.

therefore, you may get interference from other apps.  have you checked to see that no other apps are currently asking for their own updates from locationmanager?  if they are, then you app is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the technique answered here: [Best way to constantly monitor location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849197/best-way-to-constantly-monitor-location)

Answer (score 0):

You can stop listening for location updates

```
// Remove the listener you previously added
m.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Probably you have seen this post, in case of you did not it is told here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: I don't want to stop listening for updates.  I wish them to happen less often in a battery friendly way.