# Best way to constantly monitor location

Tags: android

I want to monitor a user's location on a regular basis, like Google Latitude does.  Something that would wake the phone up every X minutes, even if the app is currently not running, get the location, and send it to a server.  This is something that the user will have to opt into.

Using LocationManager alone does not seem to be the way to go.  I guess this is sort of a follow up question to this one: [LocationManager updates every minute, consuming a lot of battery power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846441/locationmanager-updates-every-minute-consuming-a-lot-of-battery-power)

It seems like using a combination of AlarmManager and LocationManager would work.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried just using `LocationManager` for this and did not have much luck. Hence, I rolled a [`LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) that, in conjunction with your own `_WAKEUP` alarms, should handle this scenario.

Comment: Thanks!  You've saved me again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into writing a service to handle this?

I would be a bit concerned about battery life though, so I'd make the 'X' configurable, if that's appropriate